# Angularjs not correctly binding to an empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a small angular app to investigate if it's going to be worth using in the future and so far I'm really enjoying how easy it is to develop in.

I've run into a snag however. I have two data models, a list of factories and a list of the products of the factories.

The products are computed when a new factory is added or removed from the list and for the most part this works fine until you remove the last factory from the list. I'd expect table that the products are bound to, to empty like the factory list as it's the underlying array becomes empty but instead the last item stays.

I don't have a fiddle showing this but I've uploaded the app to an azure site [here](http://complexity.azurewebsites.net/#/complex) and the code is up on git [here](https://github.com/Dramak/Complexity) with the key files being the app/view/complex and the app/scripts/Complex.js

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be here:

```
angular.extend(this.complexProduct, itemsProduced);
```

You're not supposed to extend an array with an array. extend is for objects. The outcome of extending an array with an empty array will end up just returning the original array.

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
angular.extend(x, []);
console.log(x); //1, 2, 3
```

try this:

```
$scope.complexProduct = itemsProduced;
```

(I prefer $scope to this because it's more specific and, IMO easier to follow)

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'd been using extend as a misunderstood attempt to combat $digest errors caused by binding directly to the Calculate method.